# What is the best way to go about grouping rows by the same timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql

Right due to not getting the right answer last time, I will reword this.

I want to create a page where all fixtures from 'tbl_fixtures' are shown.

id - compname - home_user - home_team - away_user - away_team - date

That is the table setup.
The date column is a timestamp. 
I want to show all fixtures in blocks based on the date column.

There will be blocks of 10 fixtures with the same timestamp on them. 
I want to show it like this...

Fixture 1  - (timestamp in readable format)
Then all 10 fixtures....

Fixture 2 - (timestamp)
Then 10 fixtures...

etc etc.

Until all the fixtures are grouped by their timestamp.

How could I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm not sure the format of your timestamp, but why can't you just include 'ORDER BY date' in your select statement?

Comment: I could but i want to seperate rows with different dates?

Comment: So you want to "categorize" by week?

Comment: @Luke: There is some confusion as to what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps some more details or maybe some table data and the desired record set.

Comment: @Luke did you ever find a solution for this. I know what you mean, because this is EXACTLY what I am trying to do.

Comment: Actually, I just came up with a solution. I know it's been 2 years since you posted this, so you probably came up with something that would suit your needs, but just out of curiosity... do you still need it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "group" them by weeks you can use the [`WEEK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) function. The best would be to order the rows by the timestamp and print a new week header if the week changes:

```
$result = $mysql_query("SELECT WEEK(timestamp) as week, * FROM myTable ORDER BY timestamp");

$current_week = null;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  if ($row["week"] != $current_week) {
    $current_week = $row["week"];
    echo 'Week ' . $current_week .': ';
  }
  echo $row["timestamp"];
  // echo other fields
}
```

Comment: Yeah i want them all in order of the timestamp, but when the timestamp changes, i want a new title/header.

Comment: You mean when the *week* changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to read your mind and suggest using DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`add_dt`, '%u') AS `d`, `field1`, `field2`
FROM `table1`
ORDER BY `d`
```

Where %u is week number ([ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)).